# Simple Java password rule enforcing

Tags: java, strings, security, validation, javafx

- rule 1: length must be between 8 and 50 chars.
- rule 2: at least 3 of the 4 following rules:
- --------2a: at least one upper case
- --------2b: at least one lower case
- --------2c: at least one numeral
- --------2d: at least one non-alphanumeric.

I have a function which will take in two Strings (the password and the confirmation) and then return a boolean depending on if it verified. It also sets a label on my JavaFX screen to the error or confirmation message. It works fine, but the code seems cumbersome. any thoughts?

```
public boolean validatePassword(String newPass, String confirmPass)
{
    if (newPass == null || 
        confirmPass == null || 
        newPass.length() == 0 || 
        confirmPass.length() == 0 )
    {
        responseLabel.setText("");
        return false;
    }

    boolean equalsRule = newPass.equals(confirmPass);
    boolean lengthRule = newPass.length() >= 8 && newPass.length() <= 50;

    boolean upperRule = !newPass.equals(newPass.toLowerCase());
    boolean lowerRule = !newPass.equals(newPass.toUpperCase());
    boolean numeralRule = newPass.matches("(.*)[0-9](.*)");
    boolean nonAlphaRule = newPass.matches("(.*)[^A-Za-z0-9](.*)");

    int ruleCount = (upperRule ? 1 : 0) + ( lowerRule ? 1 : 0) + ( numeralRule ? 1 : 0) + (nonAlphaRule ? 1 : 0);

    if (ruleCount >= 3 && equalsRule && lengthRule)
    {
        responseLabel.setText("Password set successfully.");
        responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!equalsRule)
        {
            responseLabel.setText("Passwords must match.");
        }
        else if (ruleCount < 3 || !lengthRule)
        {
            responseLabel.setText("Password does not follow instructions above.");
        }
        responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see at least one big problem in your method: there is **no separation of concerns**. Everything is mixed into this method: common rule for password double-checking, business rules for password validation and UI calls for user response.

## Extracting the business logic

The business logic in your case if the password validation specific *rules*, as you named them *rule1*, *rule2a*, *rule2b*, *rule2c* and *rule2d*.
Everytime you will need a password validation, you will need these rules to validate a password, therefore I would extract these rules into a BO.

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public final class Password {
    private final String value;
    private final Predicate<String> rule;

    public Password(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        Predicate<String> rule1 = s -> s.length() >= 8 && s.length() <= 50;
        Predicate<String> rule2a = s -> !s.equals(s.toLowerCase());
        Predicate<String> rule2b = s -> !s.equals(s.toUpperCase());
        Predicate<String> rule2c = s -> s.codePoints().anyMatch(Character::isDigit);
        Predicate<String> rule2d = s -> s.codePoints().anyMatch(i -> !Character.isAlphabetic(i));
        Predicate<String> rule2 = s -> Stream.of(rule2a, rule2b, rule2c, rule2d)
                                             .filter(p -> p.test(s))
                                             .count() >= 3;
        this.rule = rule1.and(rule2);
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return rule.test(value);
    }
}
```

If the rules are likely to change, it would also be possible to refactor this code and take the "final predicate" as a constructor argument.

## Extracting "standard" logic

In your case, it is *only* the rule that assert the password and the confirmation password are equals. This is not a business-specific rule but rather a commonly accepted rule everytime a user creates a password. Moreover it seems you have a "validation flow" defined (first check the equality between the two password, then check if the password in itself is valid) that can be extracted into a separate class

```
public final class PasswordInteractor {
    public ValidationResult validatePassword(String pwd, String confirmPwd) {
        if (!pwd.equals(confirmPwd)) {
            return new ValidationResult("Passwords must match.", false);
        }

        if (!new Password(pwd).isValid()) {
            return new ValidationResult("Password does not follow instructions above.", false);
        }

        return new ValidationResult("Password set successfully", true);
    }
}
```

I created a DTO `ValidationResult` to transmit to the upper layer a composite result since it can be more than `true`/`false`.

```
public final class ValidationResult {
    private final String message;
    private final boolean success;

    public ValidationResult(String message, boolean success) {
        this.message = message;
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
}
```

## Extracting UI calls

Finally the UI calls must stay in the UI-part, namely into the JavaFX controller. Typically it could looks like this (simplified):

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public final class PasswordController {
    @FXML
    private Label responseLabel;

    @FXML
    private TextField pwd;

    @FXML
    private TextField confirmPwd;

    public void validateForm() {
        // validate other parts of the form

        ValidationResult result = new PasswordInteractor().validatePassword(pwd.getText(), confirmPwd.getText());

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        }
        responseLabel.setText(result.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is extremely insightful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Start writing some utility classes, you're likely going to be checking if strings are nonempty in other places:

```
public final class StringUtils {
    public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String string) {
        return string == null || string.length() == 0;
    }

    public static boolean isNullOrWhitespace(String string) {
        if (string == null) {
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(string.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can try to generalize your password rules with an interface. A very simple approach could be just method to determine if the rule is satisfied:

```
public interface PasswordRule {
    boolean isSatisfied(String password);
}
```

And then you can implement some of your rules:

```
public class HasDigitRule implements PasswordRule {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(String password) {
        if(password == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("password cannot be null.");

        for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class HasLowerCaseRule implements PasswordRule {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(String password) {
        if(password == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("password cannot be null.");

        for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class HasNonAlphanumericRule implements PasswordRule {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(String password) {
        if(password == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("password cannot be null.");

        for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class HasUpperCaseRule implements PasswordRule {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(String password) {
        if(password == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("password cannot be null.");

        for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

public class LengthRule implements PasswordRule {
    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied(String password) {
        if(password == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("password cannot be null.");
        return password.length() >= 8 && password.length() <= 50;
    }
}
```

Now you can restructure you validation method to check all the critical cases first and exit early. Then count the amount of requirements met:

```
public boolean validatePassword(String newPassword, String confirmPassword) {
    if (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(newPassword)
            || StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(confirmPassword)) {
        responseLabel.setText("");
        return false;
    }

    if (!newPassword.equals(confirmPassword)) {
        responseLabel.setText("Passwords must match.");
        responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        return false;
    }

    PasswordRule lengthRule = new LengthRule();
    if (!lengthRule.isSatisfied(newPassword)) {
        responseLabel.setText("Passwords must be between 8 and 50 characters long.");
        responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        return false;
    }

    PasswordRule[] additionalRules = {
            new HasDigitRule(),
            new HasLowerCaseRule(),
            new HasNonAlphanumericRule(),
            new HasUpperCaseRule(),
    };

    long satisfiedRulesCount =
            Stream.of(additionalRules)
                    .filter(r -> r.isSatisfied(newPassword))
                    .count();

    if (satisfiedRulesCount < 3) {
        responseLabel.setText("Password does not follow instructions above.");
        responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        return false;
    }

    responseLabel.setText("Password set successfully.");
    responseLabel.setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
    return true;
}
```

Going forward you should consider extracting the error messages, maybe to the `PasswordRule` interface. Then you could perhaps return a list of unsatisfied conditions instead of a boolean.

Comment: Great advice! I definitely agree about the utility classes and have now implemented that. Thank you!!!